# php include from a subfolder

Tags: php

I have been using to get my files

```
<?php include 'example.html'; ?>
```

however how do you get them if they are in a subfolder: For example

```
pictures/example.html
```

Comment: Why would you include an image?

Comment: I'm guessing that the image file name in the question is just an example, and that it could be extended to any file type (such as other *.php files)

Comment: Yeh sorry I didnt mean to put .jpg I will edit it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice for this is to define a `ABSOLUTE_PATH` constant that contains the directory that everything is located under. After that, you can simply copy and paste everything, because it is defining the 'full' path, which doesn't change from directory to directory.

E.g

`define("ABS_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

or

`define("ABS_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));`
// This defines the path as the directory the file is in.
Then at any point you can simply do this to include a file

`include(ABS_PATH . "/path/to/file");`

Comment: A note of warning when using `$_SERVER`: It returns "The document root directory under which the current script is executing, _as defined in the server's configuration file_.", so in some cases might not be entirely what you'd expect it to be

Answer (score 6):

It should be just as easy as

```
<?php
include('pictures/face.jpg');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is include it like this:

```
<?php
  include('pictures/face.jpg');
?>
```

But **why are you trying to include an image?** This should be done through HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If it were a source file, you could do:

```
include __DIR__ . '/pictures/src.php';
```

But because you're dealing with a binary file (raw data, ones and zeros) you may want to use the image library:

```
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg( string $filename );
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Or, if you just want the bytes, use:

```
$contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/pictures/src.php');
```